# Can't get contact form to submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Had this working and tested it out, was getting the emails no problem. Then it quit. Which probably means I changed/deleted something but I can't figure it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns" id="form-right">
                <form id="myForm" data-abide="ajax">
                    <div class="contactform">
                    <div class="name-field">
                        <label>Your name <small>required</small>
                        <input id="name" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
                        <small class="error">Hi I'm Parker. What's your name?</small>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="email-field">
                        <label>Email <small>required</small>
                        <input id="email" type="email" required>
                        <small class="error">Oops, you forgot your email.</small>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-field">
                        <label>Message <small>required</small>
                        </label>
                        <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
                        <small class="error">I see you're the quiet type. How about a short message?</small>
                    </div>
                    <!--<button type="submit">Submit</button>-->
                    <input type="submit" name="sendbutton" id="sendbutton" class="sendbutton button radius" value="Submit" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>    
    $('#myForm')
    .on('submit', function () {
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();

        //Data for response
        var dataString = 'name=' + name +
            '&email=' + email +
            '&message=' + message;

        //Begin Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"php/mail.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('.contactform').html("<div id='thanks'></div>");
                    $('#thanks').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>Glad to hear from you "+ name +"! I'll be in touch soon.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500);
            },
            }); //ajax call
            return false;
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$msg = "

Name: $name
Email: $email
Comments: $message
";

$to = "REDACTED";
$subject = "Web Form";
$message = $msg;
$headers = "Web Form";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

**
EDIT: I HAD A WRONG PATH FOR PHP FILE. I WOULD DELETE THIS QUESTION IF I COULD. THANKS.
**

Comment: Please narrow your problem down by checking if you have any javascript errors, the form is successfully submitted and the mail function returns true. Also have you checked your spam folder? Your server may have a bad (mail)reputation, gmail is picky about that.

Comment: Well, what did you change?  I'll ask the obvious question, already knowing the answer... What does your source control history tell you?  If you need to debug the problem manually, what have you don't to debug the problem manually?  Where *specifically* does it fail?  Dumping all of your code here and essentially saying "it doesn't work, fix it" doesn't get you far here.  You need to be more specific.

Comment: thanks @David Seems I've been working too long and missed the obvious. i had mail.php outside of the php folder, so it couldn't find it. time for a break. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was quite hard to debug, i actually tried to send the form and tracked the request inside developer tools, watch this:

```
POST http://www.parker-gibson.com/php/mail.php 404 (Not Found) 
jquery.js:25fb.support.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery.js:25fb.extend.ajax
jquery.js:25(anonymous function) (index):664fb.event.dispatch
jquery.js:25r.handle jquery.js:24
```

I guess your path is wrong or you missed to upload the file...

Comment: thank you @LJ_1102 i just noticed that as well. thanks for your effort! as i was saying, i think it's time for a break!